# This is a simple stopwatch cli application with a few options

Tags: performance, c, formatting, timer, time

My goal of this when I started writing it was simply that it be able to record thousandths of a second in a very performant and accurate way. I'm not sure I have achieved the performance aspect of that though, and I am not sure how to check the accuracy. I haven't done a lot of C programming before, but I feel like there is a lot wrong with this code. One thing I noticed is that my CPU usage spikes if I leave this running in the VSCode terminal with it open, but drops down when the terminal is hidden. Maybe I need to print to the screen less often. And I have successfully built this on both macos and Linux, but I know little about portability. Anyway, the code.

Here is my header:

```c
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H
#define STOPWATCH_H

#include <stdio.h>

void set_canonical_mode(int enable);
void print_time(FILE *fd);
void clear_output();
FILE *get_saved_time_file(char *mode);
void save_time();
void restore_time();
void add_one_second();
void subtract_one_second();
void reset_time();
void cleanup();
void sigint_handler(int sig);
void* input_thread();
void print_help(FILE *out);
void print_short_help(FILE *out);

#endif
```

And here is the main file:

```c
#include "sw.h"
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ONE_MILLION_NSEC 1000000
#define ONE_BILLION_NSEC 1000000000
#define NSEC_TO_SLEEP ONE_MILLION_NSEC
#define HIDE_CURSOR printf("\e[?25l")
#define SHOW_CURSOR printf("\e[?25h")

#define OVER_HOUR_TEMPLATE "%2d:%02d:%02d.%02d"
#define UNDER_HOUR_TEMPLATE "%02d:%02d.%02d"

int paused = 0;

const struct timespec sleepduration = {0, NSEC_TO_SLEEP};

struct timespec starttime;
struct timespec currenttime;
struct timespec elapsedtime;
struct timespec restored_time;
struct timespec resumedtime;

char endchar = '\r';

int rflag = 0;
int sflag = 0;
int xflag = 0;
int pflag = 0;
int aflag = 0;

static char *program_name;

void set_raw_mode(int enable) {
  struct termios term_settings;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term_settings);

  if (enable) {
    term_settings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  } else {
    system("stty sane");
  }

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_settings);
}

void print_time(FILE *fd) {
  if (elapsedtime.tv_sec < 3600) {
    fprintf(fd, UNDER_HOUR_TEMPLATE, (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec / 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec % 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_nsec / 10000000));
  } else {
    fprintf(fd, OVER_HOUR_TEMPLATE, (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec / 3600),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec % 3600 / 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec % 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_nsec / 10000000));
  }
  fprintf(fd, "%c", endchar);
  fflush(stdout);
}

void pause_timer() {
  paused = 1;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &currenttime);
  if (xflag) {
    cleanup();
    exit(0);
  }
}

void resume_timer() {
  paused = 0;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &resumedtime);
  starttime.tv_sec += resumedtime.tv_sec - currenttime.tv_sec;
  starttime.tv_nsec += resumedtime.tv_nsec - currenttime.tv_nsec;
  if (starttime.tv_nsec < 0) {
    starttime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
    --starttime.tv_sec;
  } else if (starttime.tv_nsec >= ONE_BILLION_NSEC) {
    starttime.tv_nsec -= ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
    ++starttime.tv_sec;
  }
}

void clear_output() {
  printf("\r");
  fflush(stdout);
}

FILE *get_saved_time_file(char *mode) {
  FILE *savedtimef = NULL;
  char file[256];
  char *homedirectory = getenv("HOME");
  if (homedirectory != NULL) {
    strncpy(file, getenv("HOME"), 255);
    file[255] = '\0';
    strcat(file, "/.sw");
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(file, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)) {
      strcat(file, "/savedtime");
      savedtimef = fopen(file, mode);
    } else if (strncmp(mode, "w", 1) == 0) {
      mkdir(file, S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
      strcat(file, "/savedtime");
      savedtimef = fopen(file, mode);
    }
  }
  return savedtimef;
}

void save_time() {
  FILE *savedtimef = get_saved_time_file("w");
  if (savedtimef == NULL) {
    perror("Could not save to file");
    exit(1);
  }
  print_time(savedtimef);
}

void restore_time() {
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int seconds = 0;
  int centiseconds = 0;

  FILE *savedtimef = get_saved_time_file("r");

  if (savedtimef == NULL) {
    restored_time.tv_sec = 0;
    restored_time.tv_nsec = 0;
    return;
  }

  int bufsize = 32;
  char *buf = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
  if (buf == NULL) {
    perror("Could not allocate memory to restore previous time.\n");
  }
  memset(buf, 0, bufsize);

  fgets(buf, bufsize, savedtimef);

  if (strlen(buf) < 9) {
    perror("Restore file unparsable.");
  } else if (strlen(buf) == 9) {
    sscanf(buf, UNDER_HOUR_TEMPLATE, &minutes, &seconds, &centiseconds);
    restored_time.tv_sec = (minutes * 60) + seconds;
    restored_time.tv_nsec = (centiseconds * 10000000);
  } else {
    sscanf(buf, OVER_HOUR_TEMPLATE, &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &centiseconds);
    restored_time.tv_sec = (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
    restored_time.tv_nsec = (centiseconds * 10000000);
  }
  free(buf);

  starttime.tv_sec -= restored_time.tv_sec;
  starttime.tv_nsec -= restored_time.tv_nsec;
  if (starttime.tv_nsec < 0) {
    starttime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
    --starttime.tv_sec;
  }

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &currenttime);
  elapsedtime.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec;
  elapsedtime.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec;
  if (elapsedtime.tv_nsec < 0) {
    elapsedtime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
    --elapsedtime.tv_sec;
  }
}

void add_one_second() {
  starttime.tv_sec -= 1;
  if (paused) {
    elapsedtime.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec;
    elapsedtime.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec;
    if (elapsedtime.tv_nsec < 0) {
      elapsedtime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
      --elapsedtime.tv_sec;
    }
    print_time(stdout);
  }
}

void subtract_one_second() {
  starttime.tv_sec += 1;
  if (starttime.tv_sec > currenttime.tv_sec ||
      (starttime.tv_sec == currenttime.tv_sec &&
       starttime.tv_nsec > currenttime.tv_nsec)) {
    starttime.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec;
    starttime.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec;
  }
  if (paused) {
    elapsedtime.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec;
    elapsedtime.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec;
    if (elapsedtime.tv_nsec < 0) {
      elapsedtime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
      --elapsedtime.tv_sec;
    }
    print_time(stdout);
  }
}

void reset_time() {
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &starttime);
  if (paused) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &currenttime);
    elapsedtime.tv_sec = 0;
    elapsedtime.tv_nsec = 0;
    print_time(stdout);
  }
}

void cleanup() {
  paused = 1;
  endchar = '\n';
  clear_output();
  print_time(stdout);
  SHOW_CURSOR;
  set_raw_mode(0);
  if (sflag) {
    save_time();
  }
}

void sigint_handler(int sig) {
  cleanup();
  exit(sig);
}

void get_input() {
  fd_set read_fds;
  struct timeval timeout;
  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds);
  timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  timeout.tv_usec = 1000; // Check every 1ms
  if (select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1) {
    char c;
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    if (aflag) {
      if (pflag) {
        if (c == ' ') {
          pflag = !pflag;
        }
      } else {
        // exit upon any keypress
        cleanup();
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    switch (c) {
    case ' ':
      // pause or resume stopwatch
      if (paused)
        resume_timer();
      else
        pause_timer();
      break;
    case 's':
      save_time();
      break;
    case 'r':
      reset_time();
      break;
    case '+':
      add_one_second();
      break;
    case '-':
      subtract_one_second();
      break;
    case 'q':
      // quit
      cleanup();
      exit(0);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}

void print_short_help(FILE *out) {
  fprintf(out, "Usage: %s [-hsrxpa]\n", program_name);
}

void print_help(FILE *out) {
  print_short_help(stdout);
  fprintf(out, "\nOptions:\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -h, --help    Show this help message and exit.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -s, --save    Save the final time to ~/.sw/savedtime\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -r, --restore Restore time from ~/.sw/savedtime\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -x, --exit    Exit instead of pausing.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -p, --paused  Start in paused state.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -a, --anykey  Exit upon any keypress. With -p, will exit "
               "upon any keypress after unpausing.\n");

  fprintf(out, "\nControls:\n");
  fprintf(out, "  Space         Pause or resume the stopwatch.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  s             Save the current time to ~/.sw/savedtime.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  +             Add one second to the time.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  -             Subtract one second from the time.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  r             Reset the stopwatch to zero.\n");
  fprintf(out, "  q             Quit.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, sigint_handler);

  program_name = argv[0];

  static struct option long_options[] = {
      {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},    {"save", no_argument, 0, 's'},
      {"restore", no_argument, 0, 'r'}, {"exit", no_argument, 0, 'x'},
      {"paused", no_argument, 0, 'p'},  {"anykey", no_argument, 0, 'a'},
  };

  int opt;
  int option_index = 0;
  while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "hsrxpa", long_options,
                            &option_index)) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 'h':
      print_help(stdout);
      exit(0);
    case 's':
      sflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'r':
      rflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'x':
      xflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'p':
      pflag = 1;
      break;
    case 'a':
      aflag = 1;
      break;
    case '?':
      print_short_help(stderr);
      break;
    default:
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  set_raw_mode(1);
  HIDE_CURSOR;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &starttime);
  if (rflag) {
    restore_time();
  }
  if (pflag) {
    pause_timer();
    print_time(stdout);
    while (paused) {
      get_input();
      nanosleep(&sleepduration, NULL);
    }
  }

  while (1) {
    if (!paused) {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &currenttime);
      elapsedtime.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec;
      elapsedtime.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec;
      if (elapsedtime.tv_nsec < 0) {
        elapsedtime.tv_nsec += ONE_BILLION_NSEC;
        --elapsedtime.tv_sec;
      }
      print_time(stdout);
    }
    get_input();
    nanosleep(&sleepduration, NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here are also some future features I'd like to add. Would welcome advice on implementation:

- option to specify timer precision
- option to specify time formatting (e.g., "01:23" vs "1m23s" vs "1 minute 23 seconds".)
- option to give filepath to save to/restore from (should this be done with pipes/redirection?)
- option to start timer on keyUP. If you've ever used a rubik's cube mat, they being timing when you hand leaves the mat.
- option to set laps, and have them be saved/restored from file as well.

Comment: Another option is to create an interval timer that generates a signal every 1000th of a second. See [man 2 create_timer](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html). Understand, that timing anything on an OS that is doing lots of other things will have a small amount of error inherent in any timing mechanism you use. An interval timer is a very simple approach to the problem.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks! I checked out GNU `time` as inspiration and I believe the approach I use here is similar.

Comment: The best thing about the interval timer interface is after creating the timer, you can stop and start it many times -- just like pressing the buttons on a stopwatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Check the return value of library functions

From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> signal() returns the previous value of the signal handler. On failure, it returns SIG_ERR, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Neither of the calls to `signal()` are checked in your application.
The calls to `clock_gettime()`, `system()` `read()`, `mkdir()`, and `fgets()` et cetera also go unchecked.

[Note that there is another way of setting the terminal back to cooked mode instead of calling `system()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129698/20017547)

### Calling async-signal-unsafe functions in signal handlers is undefined behavior

`fflush()`, `fprintf()`, `printf()`, `exit()`, and `system()` are not safe to call in a signal handler according to both the ISO C and POSIX standards. See: [signal-safety(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

The behavior is also undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than `errno` with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`. The variable `paused` is of type `int`.

### `argv[0]` can be `NULL`

```c
program_name = argv[0];
```

This is risky. One can easily pass in `argv[0]` as a null pointer with an `exec()` syscall. Add a check for it, else a subsequent null pointer dereference would invoke undefined behavior.

### Use the `bool` type to denote a binary state

```c
case 's':
  sflag = 1;
  break;

case 'r':
  rflag = 1;
  break;
```

Include `stdbool.h` for `bool`, `true`, and `false`. This is not required in C2X, as they are keywords.

```c
#define C2X_PLACEHOLDER 202000L

#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= C2X_PLACEHOLDER
    /* Coast is clear. */
#else
    #include <stdbool.h>            /* bool, true, and false. */
#endif
```

You could also make a `struct` containing all these flags and pass it around as an argument instead of making all the flags global. I'd also suggest moving this input parsing to a separate function.
Furthermore, consider using `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `stdlib.h` instead of non-standard exit codes.

### In `main()`, `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` is equivalent to `return EXIT_SUCCESS`

I suggest eliding the calls to `exit()`.

### The call to `strcat()` might write to out-of-bounds memory

```c
strncpy(file, getenv("HOME"), 255);
file[255] = '\0';
strcat(file, "/.sw");
```

You failed to verify whether the string returned by `getenv()` was less than 255 characters. The subsequent calls to `strcat()` have the same problem. You're inviting a buffer overflow attack. I suggest using `strncat()`, or using one of the better alternatives to `strcat()/strncat()` that POSIX might provide.

The subsequent call to `strncmp()`:

```c
else if (strncmp(mode, "w", 1) == 0
```

can simply be:

```c
else if (mode[0] == 'w')
```

You also don't need separate invocations of `fopen()` in each branch. Move the call to the last line of the function and eliminate the unused variable (`return fopen(...)`).

### Prior to C2X, a function with empty parentheses as the argument-list specifies an argument that takes a variadic number of arguments, not zero

Specify `void` wherever you are using empty parentheses.

I also do not see what the point of `stopwatch.h` is. I'd just elide it.

### Consecutive string literals are concatenated

You can replace the 16 calls to `fprintf()` in the help message with:

```c
fprintf(out, "\nOptions:\n"
             "  -h, --help    Show this help message and exit.\n"
             "  -s, --save    Save the final time to ~/.sw/savedtime\n"
             "  -r, --restore Restore time from ~/.sw/savedtime\n"
             "  -x, --exit    Exit instead of pausing.\n"
             "  -p, --paused  Start in paused state.\n"
             "  -a, --anykey  Exit upon any keypress. With -p, will exit upon any keypress after unpausing.\n"
             "\nControls:\n"
             "  Space         Pause or resume the stopwatch.\n"
             "  s             Save the current time to ~/.sw/savedtime.\n"
             "  +             Add one second to the time.\n"
             "  -             Subtract one second from the time.\n"
             "  r             Reset the stopwatch to zero.\n"
             "  q             Quit.\n");
```

### The identifier `fd` is conventionally used for a file descriptor, and not a `FILE *`

Consider using `fp` or `stream`. Additionally, the arguments that are not modified in the function should be `const`-qualified. If you're using C99 or higher, you should also be using the `ptr[static 1]` notation for pointers that are expected to be non-null.

### Do not use dynamic allocation when a fixed-size array would suffice

In here:

```c
int bufsize = 32;
char *buf = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
if (buf == NULL) {
  perror("Could not allocate memory to restore previous time.\n");
}
memset(buf, 0, bufsize);
```

The size of the buffer is already known, and there's no reason to call `malloc()` for it. Simply do:

```c
#define BUFSIZE 32
char buf[BUFSIZE];
```

To zero-initialize it, which I don't believe has any value here:

```c
char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};

// Or in C2X, like C++:
char buf[BUFSIZE] = {};
```

And `malloc()`+`memset()` should really be `calloc()`.

Also note that `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard to be 1. So it can be safely elided.

Additionally, use an extra variable to avoid the two calls to `strlen()`.

Comment: You mean you don't see what the point of the `sw.h` file is? I thought it was just good practice to always include a header file. Doesn't it make it the order of function declaration unimportant then? And I'm not familiar with the `ptr[static 1]` notation, maybe I'm googling the wrong thing, do you have a resource?

Comment: This is a stand-alone program, and everything is in a single file, and all the functions have been defined before `main()`, so I see 0 point in putting the declarations in a header file and including that. You're not perchance trying to distribute it as a library, are you? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830403/20017547

Comment: I get "conflicting types" warnings if I remove the header. I think related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779358/how-to-resolve-conflicting-types-error-in-c

Comment: @patrick You can put all the text of the .h file into the .c file where you `#include` it. This is exactly what the pre-processor does before the compiler gets to it. There is no need for a separate header file if you aren’t going to include it in multiple source files.

Comment: Now I see what you are saying. Appreciate the patient explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This looks silly at first:

```c
#define ONE_MILLION_NSEC 1000000
#define ONE_BILLION_NSEC 1000000000
```

But considering that you cannot yet write 1'000'000 in C, this will make your code easier to read. However, you don’t use these macros!

```c
void print_time(FILE *fd) {
  if (elapsedtime.tv_sec < 3600) {
    fprintf(fd, UNDER_HOUR_TEMPLATE, (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec / 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_sec % 60),
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_nsec / 10000000));
  } …
```

I need to count zeros, which is not easy. I think you can replace that last line with

```c
            (int)(elapsedtime.tv_nsec / (10 * ONE_MILLION_NSEC)));
```

I prefer to use E notation (1e6), but I understand when people want to keep it all as integers.

That bit of code I copied above has to other constants. I suggest you add those as macros also:

```c
#define SECS_PER_MIN 60
#define SECS_PER_HOUR 3600
```

---

The other thing I wanted to comment on is program structure. You have lots of global variables that don’t need to be global — ideally you’d have zero globals. Also you have a single .c file that defines `main` and all the functions it calls, so what is the .h file useful for? You cannot include this code in another project, because it defines `main`. So this header can only ever be included in this .c file here. But it doesn’t declare anything that the .c file doesn’t already know.

I would suggest writing either a single-file program, or split up the code into meaningful, reusable modules (maybe one .c and .h that define a reusable stopwatch mechanism, and one .c file that contains `main` and does the user interaction).

---

You ask about portability. You’re using POSIX functions, so this will not compile on Windows.

Comment: What functions would I use if I wanted to be able to compile on both? Also, see my comment above about why I include the header. Is there another way of dealing with them besides rearranging the functions? I wanted the freedom to define them in whatever order I wanted. I am compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 src/sw.c`.

Comment: @patrick I don’t know how to do more complex stuff in Windows terminal, outside of reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout`. The Windows terminal works differently. But of course there are POSIX layers in Windows, like Cygwin. If you run Cygwin on a Windows computer, you get everything you need to build POSIX programs, and distribute them to people who don’t use Cygwin. Of course `system("stty sane")` will not work unless the program is run inside a POSIX terminal.